# Perform operation in a specific area on array of images

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, sorting, area

I want to perform operation to check for presence of red pixels on 10 images in a same area on in all pictures at the same time.

How do I specify area of interest where to check for pixels on an image.

Everywhere I see is just examples to highlight with a mouse, but I want to keep operation on all images in same area. 
So I want to put all pictures into array and go through same operation on all of them. If red is detected, I want to save an image to a different folder. I drew this here to give you an idea.

[image]

Comment: `img(20:40, 10:50)` as a random example

Comment: Ander , can you explain in  more detail please?

Comment: You need to use basic [matrix indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html?refresh=true). I suggest reading that page first before going any further with Matlab

Comment: @Powisss Imagine you have an image stored in an array called `img`, with a size of 100 by 100 pixels. If you want to select the entire range of pixels of the image you would do `img(1:100, 1:100)`. But If you want to select a smaller range of pixels spanning from pixel (20, 10) to pixel (40, 50) then you would do `img(20:40, 10:50)` as Ander has suggested.

Comment: Thanks Cebri, makes it clearer. But what if image is stored in rgb as 100x100x3 , is the operation still the same?

Comment: @Powisss Yes, the third dimension contains the three planes that you need for an RGB image. One plane for each color channel. Also bear in mind that in Matlab, the origin for image coordinates is the top left-hand corner.

Comment: @Powisss If the image has more than 1 slice or basically more than one channel (i.e. not grayscale), make sure you index into all of the third dimension: `img(20:40, 10:50, :)`.  This will return a RGB slice of the region you want and then you can use this region to do whatever analysis you desire.